# Pandas: How to reconstruct strings from a word per row

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I've a problem regarding reconstructing sentences with in a large Pandas DataFrame (1 500 000 rows). My aim is to reconstruct sentences out of words into a new dataframe so that there's one sentence per row. I have two Series in my DataFrame: words & tags. Each sentence is separated by an exclamation mark. On top of this I want to create two separate Series into the new DataFrame for adjectives and nouns/verbs using the tags in the original DataFrame. So here is what I have:

```
>df

word    tag

bike    NOUN
winner  NOUN
!       PUNCTUATION
red     ADJECTIVE
car     NOUN
is      VERB
fast    ADJECTIVE
!       PUNCTUATION
...     ...
```

and here is what I'd like to have

```
>df2

sent             nounverb     adj

bike winner      bike winner  None
red car is fast  car is       red fast
...
```

I've been unable to find a solution for this and as I'm a beginner in Python, I haven't been able to come up with a `for loop` that would do this for me.

EDIT:

Thank you Andy & Jesús for your quick answers. Andy's answer worked neatly, although when creating the new DataFrame a slight modification was needed on my end. It was needed to call the words as strings.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
          "sent": g.apply(lambda sdf: " ".join(sdf.word.astype(str))),
          "nounverb": g.apply(lambda sdf: " ".join(sdf[sdf.is_nounverb].word.astype(str))),
          "adj": g.apply(lambda sdf: " ".join(sdf[sdf.tag == "ADJECTIVE"].word.astype(str)))
  })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add a dummy column for is "nounverb" you can use a plain ol' groupby:

```
In [11]: df["is_nounverb"] = (df.tag == "NOUN") | (df.tag == "VERB")
```

Then you can count the `!` you've seen to enumerate the sentences:

```
In [12]: df["sentence"] = (df.word == "!").cumsum()

In [13]: df = df[df.word != "!"]

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
     word        tag  sentence  is_nounverb
0    bike       NOUN         0         True
1  winner       NOUN         0         True
3     red  ADJECTIVE         1        False
4     car       NOUN         1         True
5      is       VERB         1         True
6    fast  ADJECTIVE         1        False
```

And groupby that:

```
In [15]: g = df.groupby("sentence")

In [16]: g.apply(lambda sdf: " ".join(sdf.word))
Out[16]:
sentence
0        bike winner
1    red car is fast
dtype: object

In [17]: g.apply(lambda sdf: " ".join(sdf[sdf.is_nounverb].word))
Out[17]:
sentence
0    bike winner
1         car is
dtype: object

In [18]: g.apply(lambda sdf: " ".join(sdf[sdf.tag == "ADJECTIVE"].word))
Out[18]:
sentence
0
1    red fast
dtype: object
```

And together:

```
In [21]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({
              "sent": g.apply(lambda sdf: " ".join(sdf.word)),
              "nounverb": g.apply(lambda sdf: " ".join(sdf[sdf.is_nounverb].word)),
              "adj": g.apply(lambda sdf: " ".join(sdf[sdf.tag == "ADJECTIVE"].word))
      })

In [22]: df2
Out[22]:
               adj     nounverb             sent
sentence
0                   bike winner      bike winner
1         red fast       car is  red car is fast
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution goes over running along the first column in the dataframe and assembling a list of sentences. You can do this with a loop condition in which you skip the punctuation, for example. Then for each of those temporary words that you are gonna assemble into sentences, you should assemble a description (assuming you have a 1:1 correlation between the two).

I've put up a small example not fully functional but it should point you in the right direction.

```
a = ['bike', 'winner', '!', 'red', 'car', 'is', 'fast', '!']
b = ['noun', 'noun', 'punctuation', 'adjective', 'noun', 'verb', 'adjective', 'punctuation']

temp_word = ''
temp_nounverb = ''
temp_adjective = ''
for index,word in enumerate(a):
    if word is not '!':
        temp_word += word + ' '
        if b[index] is 'noun' or b[index] is 'verb':
            temp_nounverb += word + ' '
            temp_adjective += 'None'
        else:
            temp_nounverb += 'None'
            temp_adjective += word + ' '
    else:
        print(temp_word + ' - ' + temp_nounverb + ' - ' + temp_adjective)
        temp_word = ''
        temp_nounverb = ''
        temp_adjective = ''
```

Let me know if you need further indications and I will be glad to help.